# Using custom constants within a VB / ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm adding a test site variant to an existing ASP.NET project written in VB and I'd like to make it apparent to users they are in the test site with a different banner and background etc. I've created a new test configuration and under Compile | Advanced Compile Options I've added TEST_MODE="1" as a custom constant. Then I attempt to use the following code in the ASPX file:

```
<%
#If TEST_MODE = "1" Then
    Response.WriteFile("header_test2.htm")
#Else
    Response.WriteFile("header.htm")
#End If
%>
```

The IDE shows the first statement grayed out and doing a rebuild and deploy it is still including header.htm. I wondered if anyone has ideas on why it doesn't work or can suggest an alternative way to include different files depending on the active configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Conditional compilation constants are saved to the project file of yours, and it's not deployed to your web site.

And when the website runs, ASP.NET compiler won't find that constant.

You need to set compiler options for the website using the web.config if you want this to work in the deployed pages.

Here is a nice article on this. Hope it will help you.

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx

Comment: I would but I seem to need 15 rep points to vote and I can't see a way to accept the answer either, maybe that also needs more points?

Comment: :) no worries, but it's stange why you can't accept the answer as you should be able to. If you asked one, then you should be allowed to accept the answer.